# JSON ajax returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

So I've looked through SO and the interwebs for some guiding light but can't find anything that hits the nail on the head.

I'm trying to return a value from a function. The following will present the data in an alert, so I know it's the proper value is coming back from the JSON call:

```
function getTitle(){
      var q= 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=[VIDEOID]&key=[APIKEY]&fields=items(snippet(title))&part=snippet'

$.ajax({
      url: q, 
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data){
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          alert(data.items[0].snippet.title);
      }
  });
}
getTitle();
```

But when I try to return the data from the function like so:

```
function getTitle(){
     var q= 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=[VIDEOID]&key=[APIKEY]&fields=items(snippet(title))&part=snippet'

$.ajax({
      url: q, 
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data){
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          return data.items[0].snippet.title;
      }
  });
}
alert(getTitle());
```

I get *undefined*.

If anyone could tell me where I'm being a bonehead I would appreciate it.

Comment: why not define dataType as json?

Comment: `$.ajax` is an asynchronous call. It will not return the information by the time the alert fires.

Comment: sorry...the first iteration was dataType: "jsonp". This was one of my subsequent attempts based on googling.

so if $.ajax is asynchronous, how would I go about using the returned value? In practice, I'm not alerting the returned value but setting video titles based upon YouTube video id.

Comment: Erroneously closed.. you can also make the call synchronous should that be an absolute necessity, however you shouldn't as the page will become unresponsive in the meantime

Comment: that can happen by adding async: false to the jquery ajax attributes. However if you resort to that, you have something off with your code and should probably need to revisit it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `$.ajax` is asynchronous. The function `getTitle` will return immediately as undefined. If you want to do something with the data, put that code inside the `success` function:

```
function getTitle(){
     var q= 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=[VIDEOID]&key=[APIKEY]&fields=items(snippet(title))&part=snippet'

    $.ajax({
        url: q, 
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            setTitle(data.items[0].snippet.title);
        }
    });
}
function setTitle(title){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: works like a charm. many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous , use a callback function to get the data.

```js
function getTitle() {
  var q = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=[VIDEOID]&key=[APIKEY]&fields=items(snippet(title))&part=snippet'

  $.ajax({
    url: q,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      success(data);
    }
  });
}

function success(data) {
  alert(data.items[0].snippet.title);
}
```